# Is it possible to add anchor html in labels on blogger / blogspot?

Tags: html, anchor, blogger, label, blogspot

I know it's possible to add anchor html links in blogger posts like this:

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>
<a name="test">Test</a>
```

and this works too.

I want to apply anchor html also in labels but when I add hashtag # to label
Blogger converts # in %23 in url address, so the anchor link don't work
Any trick or solution?

Comment: I don't use blogger but maybe it's something from the editor? Also `href="#test"` will make the browser jump to the element with `id="test"` within the same page, is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes... I'm tryng to achieve this  in normal post It works but if i create a label and add hashtag# to label clicking on label url generated contain %23 character instead of # character so jumping don't work

Comment: Are you added anchor links inside template using `<a expr:href='data:post.label + "#anchor"'>links</a>`?

Comment: i have not found <a expr:href='data:post.label.. in my template but <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a> replaced with <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url+ "#anchor"'><data:label.name/></a> but don't work

Comment: Try to see this article http://template-data.blogspot.com/search/label/url?max-results=500&m=1 in there using `fragment` expression for adding anchor url

Comment: i have tried to add fragment "" in <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url fragment ""'><data:label.name  /></a> but in this mode hashtag# is displayed at end of label: https://site.blogspot.com/search/label/label#  instead of https://site.blogspot.com/search/label/#label  I have tried also <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='fragment "" + data:label.url'><data:label.name  /></a> but don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution and want share with stackoverflow community
In template html jump to widget label expand it and find following code:

```
<a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a>
```

replace it with:

```
<a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='&quot;/#&quot; + data:label.name'><data:label.name/></a>
```

or
 for jump to a anchor in an other post:

```
<a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url + &quot;/#&quot; + data:label.name'><data:label.name/></a>
```

source:
https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/blogger/4Xc38prc4Po/shW-6X1SAAAJ

Alternative solution:
replace code:

```
<a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a>
```

with following:

```
<a class='tagslist__link' expr:href='data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl path "/search/label/#" + data:label.name'><data:label.name/></a>
```

or 
 for jump to a anchor in an other post:

```
<a class='tagslist__link' expr:href='data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl path "/search/label/" + data:label.name + "/#" + data:label.name'><data:label.name/></a>
```

source:
https://disqus.com/home/discussion/zkreations1/operadores_path_params_y_fragment_en_blogger/?utm_source=reply&utm_medium=email&utm_content=read_more#comment-3503042930

https://www.zkreations.com/2017/04/path-params-fragment-blogger.html#comment-3505039635

all credits goes to the author